# How to make the corners of my border image rounder in kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy, border-image

```
        self.kk = Button(text='pushme', size_hint=(0.15,0.15), background_color =[0,0,0,1])
        self.add_widget(self.kk)
        with self.kk.canvas.before:
            BorderImage(
            size=(self.kk.width + 20 , self.kk.height-7 ),
            pos=(self.kk.x  , self.kk.y),
            border=(50, 50, 50, 50),
            source='plain-white-background.jpg')
```

I want to make the border image rounder so i added  'border' as I though this would work i increased and decreased the number but no difference, if possible could give me the answer in python language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any straightforward way to round the corners of a BorderImage, except by rounding the corners of the image it is displaying. That should actually be quite easy, so it's the most obvious option.

Within Kivy, you can use a RoundedRectangle canvas instruction, but then you can't use the normal button background properties (or must manually bind them to control the shape of that new instruction).

Comment: Im just using it to be behind the background, however this roundedrectangle feature worked with my image so thank you for your reply. For anyone else looking make sure to import rounded rectangle, e.g. from kivy.graphics import RoundedRectangle